# How can I add datarow to table multiple time as user define in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, datarow

I have created a `datatable` in my vb.net project and the `datatable` is the `datasourse` of a `datagridview`.

when a user click on the button called `btnAdd`, datarow will be added to datatable. I could do it as below for a one datarow. but there is another textbox called "`txtQuantity`" for item quantity and the user can type any number in it. So my question is, how can I add the same datarow to the datatable number of times as user mention in the txtQuantity ?

```
    Dim dr As DataRow = dtOrderingItem.NewRow

        dr("ItemCode") = clckdItemCode
        dr("ItemName") = clickdItemName
        dr("ServiceCode") = srvc
        dr("RatePerItem") = txtItemRate.Text

        dtOrderingItem.Rows.Add(dr)
        dgvCart.datasource=dtOrderingItem
```

Comment: Can you use a `For...Next` loop?

Comment: @SSS, yes, I did as you suggest. Thank you for supporting :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.TryParse()` to convert the value in your TextBox to an integer, then use that in a `For` loop as suggested by SSS.

```
Dim number As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, number) Then
    If number >= 1 Then
        Dim dr As DataRow = dtOrderingItem.NewRow
        dr("ItemCode") = clckdItemCode
        dr("ItemName") = clickdItemName
        dr("ServiceCode") = srvc
        dr("RatePerItem") = txtItemRate.Text

        For i As Integer = 1 To number
            dtOrderingItem.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        dgvCart.datasource = dtOrderingItem
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for supporting. with you guys support I could pass this step as well... thumbs up